# What is a TV news story called?

Tags: word-choice

In English, one can say something like, "did you see that news story about that girl on TV?" or during a news segment, "on to the next story".

How do you translate single a "news story" in this context? (without dropping the subject as in 「では、次」 etc.)

I thought perhaps 記事、ニュース記事 but these seem to be for written things. 報道 is the verb and I don't think you can count 報道s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ニュース safely refers to an individual news story/article, so you can simply say 「次のニュースです」, 「○○についてのニュースです」, 「5件のニュース」, 「3つのニュース」, etc.

Actually, many Japanese speakers (including me) often wonder "what's the plural form of news?" because ニュース is absolutely "countable" in Japanese.

- [英語のNEWSって何故単数扱いしかしないんでしょうか？](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1424857549)

記事 is of course for written articles.

Comment: なるほど。「さっきのニュースは深刻な口調で読み上げられた」とかは全然OKなのですね？

Comment: @ishikun はい、OKです。

Answer (score 5):

In English, you can use "news story" to refer to a single piece of news covering any issue. However, it seems redundant to use "news + story" in Japanese and using "ニュース" for a news story will be sufficient. For example:

> ニュースを見ましたか? Did you watch the news?

Answer (score 3):

I think people usually just use ニュース, as in:

> - 「次のニュースです。」
>     On to the next story.
> - 「きのうのニュース、見た？」
>     Did you see the news yesterday?
> - 「あの女の子のニュース、テレビで見た？」
>     Did you see that news story about that girl on TV?

Answer (score 1):

I might not have a perfect answer for you but here is what I got.
記事 is indeed, as far as I know, for news story in the journal.
For TV perhaps the closest I got is  "コーナー". It might sound weird, but I heard it quite a few times. You might also hear them say 次の件（案件）when transitioning, but not 100% sure. Gotta have to pay more attention tomorrow morning when watching the news.

Answer (score 0):

When we are referring to a news story in general, we say "ニュース," for example, “彼女が結婚するという話、聞いた？- Did you hear the news she is going to marry?

When we are referring to “a news story” of TV, we say “(テレビの)ニュース.”

When we are referring to “a news story” of newspaper, we say “(新聞の)記事,” rather than “(新聞の)ニュース.

"報道" which means “news reporting” is a noun. Its verb form is "報道する." It's a big word as compared with "(TV, 新聞で)知らせる(伝える）.”